# Redraw text over clearRect HTML5 Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw text (HTML5 canvas) depending on what option is selected in a select element. It works correctly until there's 2 set of text that appears at the same place. It seems like the clearRect function is the issue. The text won't be redrawn over that cleared space. Here's my jQuery code for that part :

```
//DROPDOWN
$("#bureau").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "ste-julie-droite") {
        // BUREAU
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company", 260, 160, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("123 Street City", 260, 172, 225);
    } else {
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#333";
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 160, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 172, 225, 16);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "ste-julie-gauche") {
        // BUREAU
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company", 12, 155, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("123 Street City", 12, 167, 225);
    } else {
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#333";
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 167, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 155, 225, 16);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "beauceville-droite") {
        // BUREAU - 1
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company 2", 260, 149, 225);
        // BUREAU - 2
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Sub-title 1", 260, 160, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("8899 Super street", 260, 172, 225);
    } else {
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#333";
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 149, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 160, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 172, 225, 16);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "beauceville-gauche") {
        // BUREAU - 1
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company 2", 12, 147, 225);
        // BUREAU - 2
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Sub-title 1", 12, 158, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("8899 Super street", 12, 170, 225);
    } else {
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#333";
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 147, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 158, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 170, 225, 16);
    }
});
```

Is there another option I could use to make my text appear on top of the cleared section? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is that you move all your clearRect()'s out from the else-statements to the top and clear it from the start. Then you add text in a second step. That way you can also group the if-statements together to form a if-else if relationship (crappy explanation, just look below ;) ).

```
$("#bureau").change(function () {
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 149, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 160, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(260, 172, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 147, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 155, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 158, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 167, 225, 16);
        oCtx.clearRect(12, 170, 225, 16);

    if ($(this).val() == "ste-julie-droite") {
        // BUREAU
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company", 260, 160, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("123 Street City", 260, 172, 225);
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "ste-julie-gauche") {
        // BUREAU
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company", 12, 155, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("123 Street City", 12, 167, 225);
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "beauceville-droite") {
        // BUREAU - 1
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company 2", 260, 149, 225);
        // BUREAU - 2
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Sub-title 1", 260, 160, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("8899 Super street", 260, 172, 225);
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "beauceville-gauche") {
        // BUREAU - 1
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company 2", 12, 147, 225);
        // BUREAU - 2
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Sub-title 1", 12, 158, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("8899 Super street", 12, 170, 225);
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! It worked. I understand what was wrong now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need work with your X,Y locations little bit more and you should write your else if loop such a way that only one condition triggers at a time

You should always do a clearRect in first place and forget about the 260 X location

```
$("#bureau").change(function () {
    oCtx.fillStyle = "#333";
    oCtx.clearRect(12, 147, 225, 16);
    oCtx.clearRect(12, 158, 225, 16);
    oCtx.clearRect(12, 170, 225, 16);

    if ($(this).val() == "ste-julie-droite") {
        // BUREAU
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company", 12, 149, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("123 Street City", 12, 160, 225);
    } else if ($(this).val() == "ste-julie-gauche") {
        // BUREAU
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company 1", 12, 149, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("123 Street City", 12, 160, 225);
    } else if ($(this).val() == "beauceville-droite") {
        // BUREAU - 1
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company 2", 12, 149, 225);
        // BUREAU - 2
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Sub-title 1", 12, 160, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("8899 Super street", 12, 172, 225);
    } else if ($(this).val() == "beauceville-gauche") {
        // BUREAU - 1
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Company 3", 12, 149, 225);
        // BUREAU - 2
        oCtx.font = "11px Vonnes"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("Sub-title 1", 12, 160, 225);
        //VILLE
        oCtx.font = "11px VonnesReg"; // different font
        oCtx.fillStyle = "#67686a";
        oCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text baseline at the top
        oCtx.fillText("8899 Super street", 12, 172, 225);
    }
});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/ka1urxt9/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Niddro was a minute quicker ;)